# open a new browser from webview

Tags: android, browser, webview

I created an android app with webview.

Within the web page I have amazon banners.

If a user clicks on that banner I would like it to be open in the native android browser and not in webview.

I've tried several methods after searching and trying with no success.
When the banner is clicked - the app still shows the amazon site in webview mode.

Can anyone help me fix this issue ?

Your help is greatly appreciated...

Below is the code I use :

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
      if(url.contains("amazon-adsystem.com")) {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
           startActivity(i);
      }
      view.loadUrl(url);
      loadAd();
      return true;
   }
});

webView.loadUrl("http://starter_url");

loadAd();
```

Comment: What does the `loadAd()` function do? Also, are you getting any warnings or errors that you could show us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function *shouldOverrideUrlLoading()* should:

> Returns True if the host application wants to leave the current
>   WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

So you have to change your code to something like:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
        if(url.contains("amazon-adsystem.com")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.but after modifying the code - when clicking the amazon banner it is still redirecting to amazon in a webview ;(

Comment: as for the loadAd(); , it is the amazon ad that shows in the bottom of the app...

Comment: no warnings or errors. simply refuse to launch browser when amazon banner is clicked...

Comment: can you check if the ad url contains "amazon-adsystem.com"?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. yes, this was the problem. changed the "amazon-adsystem" to "amazon" and it worked !

Comment: sorry for being such a newbie but how do I do that?

Comment: on the left of the answer you will see the points given by the users and a mark that only you can check if you consider that the answer have solved your question ;)